# Xpath y atributos del padre

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Estoy scrapeando una web con la siguiente estructura

```
<tbody>
   <tr class='Leaguestitle'>...<\tr>
   <tr id='tr1_abababa'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_abababa'>..<\tr>
   .
   .
   <tr id='tr1_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_acacaca'>..<\tr>
   <tr align='center'>..<\tr>
   .
   .
   <tr id='tr1_cbcbcbc'>..<\tr>
   <tr id='tr2_cbcbcbc'>--<\tr>
   <\tbody>
```

Cada nodo tiene después sus hijos con información relevante. Para sacar los nodos que quiero, utilizo un xpath:

```
allrows=table.find_elements_by_xpath(
        './/tr[@class="Leaguestitle"] | .//tr[contains(@id,"tr1")] | .//tr[@align="center"]')
```

E itero para `row in allrows:`

El problema es que para saber a qué tipo de los 3 pertenece cada nodo, necesito que en el nodo row aparezca el tag `tr` mientras que con esa búsqueda me salen solo los hijos de cada nodo`tr`

He intentado solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
row=row.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

Que en teoría devuelve el nodo padre, cosa que veo que ocurre cuando hago

```
print(row.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento hacer un filtrado de acuerdo a los atributos de cada nodo `tr` tanto

```
row.get_attribute('class')
```

como

```
row.get_attribute('id')
```

Me los devuelve como vacíos para todos los nodos, cuando no debería. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Clasificar lista de nodos por atributo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128040/clasificar-lista-de-nodos-por-atributo)

Answer (score 0):

Puede que lo que no esté del todo correcto sea el xpath y la forma de utilizar los OR, yo los utilizo por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
.//tr[@class="Leaguestitle" or contains(@id,"tr1") or @align="center"]
```

También comprobaria la longitud de la lista de elementos, una vez que son encontrados. Para asegurar que los encuentra y son los que necesitas.

De todas formas intentara mejorar la pregunta ya que no queda muy claro que objetos son exactamente los que quieres obtener de ese trozo de html.

Comment: El problema no es encontrar los nodos que quiero, eso lo consigo. El problema es que tras hacerlo, si quiero ir 1 a 1 con un for, y clasificarlo a la lista A o la lista B en función a si tienen "tr1" en el id o class "Leaguestitle", no puedo hacerlo porque lo que obtengo no es el <tr>..<\tr> si no los nodos de dentro, es decir, el ".."

Comment: Entonces el problema es esta linea `row=row.find_element_by_xpath('..')` porque cada row ya es un tr, no hace falta subir al padre de este. Al hacerlo te estas posicionando en el body. Comenta esa linea y todo lo demas deberia ser correcto.