# Clasificar lista de nodos por atributo

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Estoy parseando esta web http://www.nowgoal.com. Para ello necesito saber el encabezado, en el que viene la fecha completa, más los nodos que contienen cada partido. Necesito hacerlo de manera secuencial, porque en la misma tabla hay más de un encabezado con fechas distintas. Cuando se alcanza la fila que pone "Results", salir.

[image: Layout 1]

[image: Layout 2]

Para ello, lo que hago es crear una lista que contenga todos los nodos de los 3 tipos

```
<tr class="Leaguestitle">   Los nodos de título
<tr id="tr1....">           Los nodos con cada partido
<tr align="center">         El nodo Results
```

Utilizo el siguiente xpath que me da la lista de nodos:

```
allrows=table.find_elements_by_xpath(
        './/tr[@class="Leaguestitle"] | .//tr[contains(@id,"tr1")] | .//tr[@align="center"]')
```

Lo que quiero es hacer un bucle for, y clasificar los nodos de la siguiente manera:

- Si es class="Leaguestitle", guardar la fecha en una variable
- Si es id="tr1...", generar una lista con todos esos nodos y la fecha en la variable
- Si es align="center" finalizar

El problema es que cada nodo del bucle en lugar de ser

[image: Nodo deseado]

Con el nodo tr y sus atributos, lo que obtengo es esto

[image: Nodo obtenido]

Que al no disponer de `tr` no me permite filtrar por los atributos.

¿Cómo lo hago para obtener el nodo con todo?

Answer (score 0):

Vale he descubierto el problema. Para mirar el nodo estaba utilizando `row.get_attribute("innerHTML")` que me daba el interior, si utilizo `row.get_attribute("outerHTML")` me sale el nodo completo, con lo que debería de ser capaz de hacer lo que quiero utilizando `row.get_attribute()`